# A basic short intro to KDE

Tags: references, nonparametric, kernel-smoothing

I'm an applied mathematician working on approximation theory and its applications to optics. I've been working with a Gaussian Kernel Density Estimator (KDE) for some while, but figured out I should be looking broader, and understand better what kernel I should be working with and how.

I'm looking for a shorter-then-text book introduction to KDE's, either as a short review, book chapter or even a slideshow. The **main questions** I need to be adressed:

1. What is the main criteria for choosing a specific KDE method over the other?
2. I understand the meaning of the "window size", but what are the main methods for choosing it?

Comment: Does this help https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/244012/35989 ?

Comment: @Tim it helps immensly, but it also helped me to sharpen my question. See new edit

Comment: (1) What do you mean by "specific KDE method"? (2) There is lots of methods, it was answered here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168/choosing-a-bandwidth-for-kernel-density-estimators

Comment: By (1) I mean, what specific kernel function to use, i.e., Gaussian, Bspline etc. @Tim

Comment: Bspline is not a kernel and the choice of the kernel in general does not matter for vast majority of the cases.